# Can i call constructor function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have created a constructor function in javascript

```
function hello () {
    name = 'shahin';
    age= 22;
    mesg = function () {
        return 'My name is ' + this.name + 'and i am '+ this.age + 'old';
    }
}

console.log(hello.mesg());
```

and instead creating of new constructor from it i just wanted to whether it is working as a normal function or not. hence try with the console and see that error : "TypeError: hello.mesg is not a function.

`

```
function hello () {
    this.name = 'shahin';
    this.age= 22;
    this.mesg = function () {
        return 'My name is ' + this.name + ' and i am '+ this.age + ' years old';
    }
}

console.log(hello.mesg())
```

I even try with this and got the same error

Comment: Your first one just creates a bunch of global variables.

Comment: If you call a constructor function without the `new` keyword, `this` will be bound to `window`.

Answer (score 1):

To understand your question properly, you need to know the return value of a function.

```
(function(){
    var a = 1;
})();
```

This returns *undefined*, since there's no any return value designated.

```
(function(){
    var b = 2;    
    return b;
})();
```

This obviously returns *b*.

Can you distinguish the difference? So, the case #1 and case #2, hello function doesn't point anything as a return value, that's why it returns *undefined* and you couldn't be able to access *mesg* method.

To work this out properly, there're bunch of possible ways, I'll give you one of examples.

```
function hello() {
    var name = 'shahin';
    var age= 22;
    var mesg = function () {
        return 'My name is ' + name + 'and i am '+ age + ' old';
    };

    return {
        getName: mesg
    };
}

var func = hello();
func.getName(); // print 'My name is ... '
```

Comment: `getName` will print `"My name is undefinedand i am undefinedold"` - Remove all `this` references and use lets/vars

Comment: you still need to remove `this`, otherwise you're adding the `mesg` function to `window`

Answer (score 0):

**In the second case**, `mesg` is the instance's variable of `hello`, you need to invoke it by instantiating with new operator.

```
console.log((new hello()).mesg())
```

**In the first case**, you can't invoke `mesg` as a property. You invoke mesg only if you return the mesg function

```
function hello () {
    name = 'shahin';
    age= 22;
    return mesg = function () {
        return 'My name is ' + this.name + 'and i am '+ this.age + 'old';
    }
}
console.log(hello()());
```

Comment: Not in the first case it's not

Comment: It's not a property of the prototype in either version.

Comment: The way OP is using `hello`, just calling `mesg` directly will work (in both cases).

Comment: where's the second function?

Comment: thank you @gurvinder372
what if there is two function inside this

 `function hello () {
    name = 'shahin';
    age= 22;
    return mesg = function () {
        return 'My name is ' + this.name + 'and i am '+ this.age + 'old';
    }
   
return mesg1 = function () {
        return 'My name is ' + this.name + 'and i am '+ this.age + 'old';
    }
} `

how can i evoke the 2nd function there? i mean mesg1()

Comment: @Sanjidalina Unless they are instance's variables like in your second case, they are private variables. You can't invoke them unless you wrap them in an object and return that object.